# Cisco 2950 switch LED off timeout

Tags: cisco, switch, packet-loss

Some random ports led turns off for less than a second https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUl4ifveh74 
Right in that time i have 2 timeouts in one or more ports which turned off .
why is it doing that?

firmware is up to date . ports are ok and tried with other ports .

show log
Note: The changed states are by hand and normal

```
00:41:31: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/23, changed state to down
00:41:33: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/23, changed state to up
00:41:50: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/23, changed state to down
00:41:52: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/23, changed state to up
00:42:00: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/22, changed state to down
00:42:02: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/22, changed state to up
00:42:05: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/22, changed state to down
00:42:07: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/22, changed state to up
00:42:22: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/22, changed state to down
00:42:24: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/22, changed state to up
1d03h: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/11, changed state to down
1d03h: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/17, changed state to down
1d03h: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface FastEthernet0/11, changed state to down
1d03h: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface FastEthernet0/17, changed state to down
1d03h: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface FastEthernet0/17, changed state to up
1d03h: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface FastEthernet0/11, changed state to up
1d03h: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/17, changed state to up
1d03h: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/11, changed state to up
```

show interface

http://paste.ubuntu.com/7541959/

One more thing . Pinging the switch is abnormal . I am far from switch and normal ping should be less than ~10ms . But as you can see the ping goes high decussate

```
Reply from x.x.x.x: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=255
Reply from x.x.x.x: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=255
Reply from x.x.x.x: bytes=32 time=181ms TTL=255
Reply from x.x.x.x: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=255
Reply from x.x.x.x: bytes=32 time=195ms TTL=255
Reply from x.x.x.x: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from x.x.x.x: bytes=32 time=215ms TTL=255
Reply from x.x.x.x: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=255
Reply from x.x.x.x: bytes=32 time=226ms TTL=255
Reply from x.x.x.x: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=255
Reply from x.x.x.x: bytes=32 time=242ms TTL=255
Reply from x.x.x.x: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=255
Reply from x.x.x.x: bytes=32 time=255ms TTL=255
Reply from x.x.x.x: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=255
Reply from x.x.x.x: bytes=32 time=273ms TTL=255
Reply from x.x.x.x: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=255
Reply from x.x.x.x: bytes=32 time=285ms TTL=255
Reply from x.x.x.x: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=255
Reply from x.x.x.x: bytes=32 time=298ms TTL=255
Reply from x.x.x.x: bytes=32 time=40ms TTL=255
```

Comment: Is your question _'why is it doing that?'_?

Comment: Please edit in the output of show log and show interface

Comment: @MikePennington Done .

Comment: Which ports are we seeing in the video? The port numbers are not visible. Also what are the ports connected to? Also please clear the interface counters and do a show interface output again so that we can see which counters are actually increasing.

Comment: Another thing, high ping times probably mean that the CPU is busy, so 'show cpu process sort' is probably helpful.

Comment: @Sebastian CPU utilization for five seconds: 24%/13%; one minute: 24%; five minutes: 24%

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: No the answers does not help . The problem disappeared by reducing the switch usage and unplugging few ports .

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a hardware fault.  This is not standard nor accepted behavior.  I'd agree with Mr. Lock and test your cables.  Beyond that, try re-loading the IOS image on the switch.  If all of that fails, you might need to replace the switch.

Answer (score 1):

you have to check the connected cables to your switch:

1. you need to check it for poor termination from Both ends
2. you need to check how long is your cables and to which category they belong and if they are passing close to electricity cables

Comment: may be useful: test cable-diagnostics tdr interface gigabitEthernet x/y/z

Comment: @pyatka, while a great feature, this is not part of the functionality of the 2950 platform. It was added on the 2960 series.